# MVVMLight - how to get a reference to the ViewModel in the View?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm building a Windows Phone 7 app, and I need a reference to my ViewModel in my view so I can set a property from my event handler. The only problem is that I'm not able to get that reference.

What I did;

I have a ViewModelLocator (deleted the irrelevant bits):

```
static ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TunerViewModel>();
}

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic", Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
public TunerViewModel Tuner
{
    get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TunerViewModel>(); }
}
```

And a view (XAML):

```
DataContext="{Binding Tuner, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

And the code-behind of the view:

```
public partial class Tuner : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private readonly TunerViewModel _viewModel;

    public Tuner()
    {
        _viewModel = DataContext as TunerViewModel;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

I found this link [MVVM View reference to ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539591/mvvm-view-reference-to-viewmodel) where the DataContext is casted to a ViewModel, so I tried the same because it looks like a good solution. However, my _viewModel field is null after the cast. Why is this and how do I fix this? I couldn't find it on Google/Stackoverflow

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you set up the Locator in your App.xaml resources (or alternatively, but not as DRY, in your page resources)?  Because this looks like it isn't finding the viewmodel in your XAML binding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you set the `DataContext` from XAML with a binding expression in the View's constructor the `DataContext` is not set yet. That's why you get null.

Try the cast the `DataContext` in or after the [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596558%28vs.95%29) event:

```
public Tuner()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += OnTunerLoaded;
}

private void OnTunerLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    _viewModel = DataContext as TunerViewModel;
}
```

Comment: To be exact, the key is to get the VM after InitializeComponent is called, because this is where the XAML is parsed and where the VM is created on demand. So, strictly speaking, you don't need the Loaded event, you just need to set your _viewModel attribute after InitializeComponent returns :)

Comment: @LBugnion is the behavior changed in WP7? Because in WPF if I set the `DataContext` in XAML it is `null` in the the usercontrol's constructor even after the `InitializeComponent()` call...

Comment: This is not what I observe. If I do File, New Project, WPF4 MVVM Light project, and place a breakpoint after InitializeComponent, the DataContext is not null, it is set. Do you observe something else?

Comment: @LBugnion Yes, I figured out what was the difference. I tested the `DataContext` with a "child view" like this: `<StackPanel>            <WPF:TestView DataContext="{Binding ..." />...` and then DataContext will remain null in the TestView's contructor. But if I set the `DataContext` the mvvm light way so inside TestView.xaml `<UserControl x:Class="WPF.TestView" DataContext="..." />` then it's really not null after the InitializeComponent.